# How to use this for 'if' statement in jinja2 template

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, jinja2

I'm trying to write an if statement in a Jinja2 template:

```
let temp_html = `<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
            <p>${comment}</p>
            <footer class="blockquote-footer">${name}</footer>
            {% if session['user_id'] == ? %}
            <div class="modify">modify</div>
            {% endif %}
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>`
```

=> in the ajax

I want to compare ${name} to session['user_id'] using the {% if ~ %} as I wrote.

How can I write ${name} in the 'if' statement within the Jinja2 template?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 session['user_id'] ? 'if true' : 'if false'
```

Comment: I don't want to check the session. The purpose is to compare with ${name}.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.